# Computing sparse eigenvectors of psd matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms, quadratic-programming

Let $A$ be an $m \times m$ psd matrix (with $m$ large) and let $s \in \{0,1,\ldots,m\}$. Let $\mathscr C_s := \{v \in \mathbb R^m \mid \|v\|_2 = 1,\;\|v\|_0 \le s\}$ be the set of all $s$-sparse unit-vectors in $\mathbb R^m$.

> **Question.** What is an efficient (and correct!) way to compute a vector $v \in \mathscr C_s$ which maximizes $v^TAv$ ?

The case $s = m$ corresponds to computing a leading eigenvetor of $A$ and can by accomplished via the [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

Comment: Unfortunately, the set $\mathscr C_s$ is not convex. However, I suspect that the $1$-norm relaxation of this problem can be written as a [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming)

Comment: Sure, one can always do such a convex relaxation, but I'm interested in the $\ell_0$ problem. Note that *nonconvex != cannot be solved (exactly)*. For example the problem: $\arg\max_{v \in \mathscr C_s}v^Ta$  (for fixed $a \in \mathbb R^m$) is nonconvex but can be solved exactly :)

Comment: You might have some luck trying to use the rank of $A$ somehow. For example, the simplified version that you present solves the case where $A$ has rank $1$. When $A = a_1a_1^T + a_2 a_2^T$, The problem becomes that of maximizing $(v^Ta_1)^2 + (v^Ta_2)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer.** *Sorry for answering my own question. Should've thought about it a bit more before posting on math.SE...*

---

So, let $B$ be any real matrix with $m$ rows such that $A=B^TB$ (such a $B$ exists because $A$ is psd). The main problem can be rewritten as

$$
\sqrt{\max_{v \in \mathscr C_s}v^TAv} = \max_{v \in \mathscr C_s}\|Bv\|_2 = \max_{v \in \mathscr C_s}\max_{\|x\|_2 \le 1}x^TBv = \max_{\|x\|_2 \le 1}\max_{v \in \mathscr C_s}v^T(B^Tx). \tag{1}
$$

We consider the following subproblem.

> **Sub-problem.** Given $u \in \mathbb R^m$, find $v \in \mathscr C_s$ which maximizes $v^Tu$.

One can easily show that

> **Lemma.** *The above sub-problem is solved by taking
> $v = \varphi_s(u):= T_s(u)/\max(\|T_s(u)\|_2, 1)$, where $T_s(u) \in \mathbb R^m$ is a vector obtained from $u$ by zero-ing out the $m-s$ entries with the smallest absolute values.*

The operator $T_s$ is sometimes referred to as *hard-thresholding.* Problem *(1)* can then be solved via the following simple iterative scheme

- **x-update:** $x_{k} \leftarrow Bv_k/\|Bv_k\|_2$
- **v-update:** $v_{k+1} \leftarrow \varphi_s(B^Tx_k)$

which can further be simplified to just one-line program involving the original matrix $A$:

- $v_{k+1/2} \leftarrow Av_k$, $v_{k+1} \leftarrow \varphi_s(v_{k+1/2}/(v_k^Tv_{k+1/2})^{1/2})$

**Convergence.** I've not yet worked this out, but adapting the proof of of convergence of the standard "power iteration" algorithm, it shouldn't be too hard to show that $\lim_{k \to \infty}v_k \in \arg\max_{v \in \mathscr C_s}v^TAv$.

Comment: Your solution is correct but notice that convergence is only guaranteed to a stationary point, not to the ground truth maximum. This is a result of the problem being non-convex. However there is vast research on sparse optimization in general and sparse PCA in specific.